# SQL help joining tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

I have a table

Assets table

```
Asset Id | Asset Name | Asset Type | Product Id
```

Transfers Table

```
Transfer Id | From Asset ID | To Asset Id | Product Id
```

I'm trying to join these table to get me

```
Transfer ID | From Asset Name | To Asset Name | Product Id
```

I used

```
Select *
From Transfer
Left join Asset on asset.id = from_asset_id or asset.id = to_asset_id
```

But I'm getting the output in different rows for the from asset name and to asset name.I want it to be in a same column not rows.

Can anyone help me, how should I query to get to my output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want two joins, as in:

```
select t.id, 
    a1.name from_asset_name, 
    a2.name to_asset_name,
    t.product_id
from transfers t
inner join assets a1 on a1.id = t.from_asset_id
inner join assets a2 on a2.id = t.to_asset_id
```

I am not sure why you would use `left join` here - unless the two asset columns are nullable.

Answer (score 0):

I made an attempt using slightly different notation from that of the accepted answer, but you could also use the following:

```
select t1.transfer_id, t2.asset_name as from_asset_name,
t3.asset_name as to_asset_name, t1.product_id from transfers as t1
inner join assets as t2 on t1.from_asset_id=t2.asset_id
inner join assets as t3 on t1.to_asset_id=t3.asset_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

an other way to do it is by:

```
SELECT
  t.transfer_id,
  a1.asset_name AS from_asset_name,
  a2.asset_name AS to_asset_name,
  t.product_id
FROM
  transfers t
INNER JOIN
  assets a1 ON a1.asset_id = t.from_asset_id
INNER JOIN
  assets a2 ON a2.asset_id = t.to_asset_id;
```

the result of this query will include the transfer ID, the corresponding from asset name, the corresponding to asset name, and the product ID, all in the same row for each transfer.